# How should I unit test a method that contains GET calls to external services

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, mocking

I am coding unit tests in my Go API with Gin Gonic.

Here is my code.

```
func getKeys(c *gin.Context) {
    var meters []models.Meter

    metadataOperation, err := metadata.GetOperation("AC123456")
    if err != nil {
        sendInternalError(err, c)
        return
    }
    meter, err := metadata.GetMeter("12345")
    // Other instructions
    // ...
    // operation = ...
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, operation)
}
```

Here is GetOperation method:

```
func GetOperation(operationID string) (Operation, error) {
    var operation Operation
    var url = metadataAPIURL + "/v2/operations/" + operationID
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        return Operation{}, err
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth(metadataAPIUser, metadataAPIPassword)
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return Operation{}, err
    }
    if res.StatusCode != 200 {
        return Operation{}, errors.New(res.Status)
    }
    err = json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&operation)
    if err != nil {
        return Operation{}, err
    }
    return operation, nil
}
```

Thing is `metadata.GetOperation("AC123456")` will make a GET request to an external service.

As I understand unit testing, I can't have any external dependencies.

In my case, test is passing, but it is making a GET request to my production server which is not the wanted result.

If I want to use mocks, I should have an interface, and switch between dependency, and mock.

It should be great to test `GetOperation` method, but for `getKeys` method, it seems unclear to me how should I do it.

How should I deal with this situation? Can anyone give me an example / tuto about this case.

Comment: Use net/http/httptest. It provides all you need, e.g. Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, refactor your `GetOperation` method to accept the URL as parameter.

```golang
func GetOperation(url, operationID string) (Operation, error)...
```

Then, use `net/http/httptest` and create a test server:

```golang
    testServer := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        res.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        res.Write(expectedData)
    }))
    defer func() { testServer.Close() }()
```

Finally, pass the test server URL as parameter to `GetOperation`:

```golang
GetOperation(testServer.URL, 'some-operation')
```

Validate that the function calls the url correctly and retrieves the `expectedData` you've passed into the test server.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two common ways to do that in unit tests, that I know.

First is to mock the request (e.g. Create `Requester` interface or something like that to wrap real GET request) and then replace it with a mock object in unit-test. It called dependency injection.

The second way is to run the test server using `net/http/httptest` and replace `metadataAPIURL` to localhost URL. See the example [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server).

Comment: You cannot mock an HTTP request, as it is is a concrete type.